# Reusing QMutex and QWaitCondition

Tags: qt, qt4, nokia, carbide

Are QMutex+QWaitCondition objects reusable?
I have a method to wait for some threads to complete.

```
void FinishWait()
{
    mutex.lock();
    waitCondition(&qMutex, ULONG_MAX);
}
```

The waitCondition.wakeOne() is called on a different Thread.

The first call to FinishWait() works but the the second call doesn't return even if I specify timeout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming "mutex" and "qMutex" mean the same variable (it doesn't make much sense otherwise), you need to unlock the mutex after the wait() returns.

```
void FinishWait()
{
    mutex.lock();
    waitCondition.wait(&mutex);
    mutex.unlock();
}
```

---

Comment: The documentation http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwaitcondition.html#wait says: "The mutex will be unlocked, and the calling thread will block until either of these conditions is met...."

Comment: And if you read further I am pretty sure the documentation says something like "If the wait() function exits, the mutex is atomically locked again", because thats the semantics of a wait condition.